# CSS not showing background ONLY IF it's in .css archive. All the other parts work properly. If I add the CSS to the HTML, the background shows

Tags: html, css, background

The CSS in another archive works properly, it shows everything in my HTML. But somehow the background doesn't work.

Before you ask:
Yes, it's everything in the same folder
Yes, I did the link properly. If I add the same code to the HTML archive, it works. But if I add it to the CSS, it doesn't. All the other parts of the CSS work in the .css archive.

I have tried naming body, html before the .class. I have tried calling it in the . The background, with the same code, works properly only if it's in the HTML archive. In the moment I change it to the CSS, the background becomes white.

Any Idea? I have tried everything I read, and anything works. And doesn't really makes sense that everything works but the background!

```
    body, html  .bg {
        background-image: url("fondo.svg");
        height: 100%;
        background-position: center;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-size: cover;
        background-attachment:fixed; min-width: 100%;   min-height: 100%;}

    #centrador {margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto; background-attachment: fixed;}

#UK {background-image: url("UKFLAG.png"); background-size:cover; background-position:center;}

            .izquierdaTOP {text-align:center;border:5px  ; border:5px outset; #000; padding:8px; padding:8px; background-color:white; opacity:0.90;width:10%;border:2px;padding:8px; position:absolute; top:0; left:0%;  margin:auto;  margin-left:10px; margin-top:10px; }

            .derechaTOP {text-align:center;border:50px  ; border:20px; padding:8px; padding:8px; background-color:white; opacity:0.90;width:10%;   border: silver 7px solid;
 
  padding: 10px; padding:8px; position:absolute; top:0; right:0%; margin:auto;  width:350px; margin-right:10px; margin-top:10px;}

    .centrado{text-align:center;border:5px outset; #000; padding:8px;}
        header, div, section, article, footer{width:50%;border:1px outset; #000;padding:8px;margin:auto; background:white; opacity:0.97 ;}
        center{margin:16px 0;}
}
#league {box-shadow: 5px -5px 0 2px #444;   text-shadow: 2px 2px 0 #AAA; border-image-source: url("https://i.pinimg.com/originals/38/46/45/384645893d3737df5f0a1a265c2987f8.png"); border-image-slice:27;}

.derechaABAJO {text-align:center;border:50px  ; border:20px; padding:8px; padding:8px; background-image: url("https://i.pinimg.com/originals/69/61/ab/6961ab1af799f02df28fa74278d78120.png"); background-position: center;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-size: cover;
     opacity:0.90;width:10%;   border: silver 7px solid;  padding: 10px; padding:8px; position:absolute; top:60%; right:0%; margin:auto;  width:350px; box-shadow: 10px 10  px 0 14px #444;   text-shadow: 1px 1px 0 #AAA; margin-right:10px; margin-top:10px;}
}
```

This is the conflcitive part

```
 `body, html  .bg {
    background-image: url("fondo.svg");
    height: 100%;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-attachment:fixed; min-width: 100%;   min-height: 100%;}`
```

it perfectly works in the html but not in the CSS

Comment: It's your first post, so I'll go easy. You'll find it best to provide code examples, or screenshots, it'd help us get an answer for you.

Comment: For example, can you copy and paste your CSS where you're trying to include the image file?

Comment: Hello @FluxCoder I edited the post with the code. Thank you!! 
The conflictive part works only in the HTML, but not when added to the CSS archive. I've tried using an URL instead of a local archive, using the .bg as a class in the body... Everything! and nothing works.